# Binomial vs inverse binomial transform in obtaining moments

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics, moments

I am trying to obtain raw co-moment matrices from central co-moment matrices and I have found formulas for the transition from central to raw moments [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RawMoment.html) . I have also found the opposite, that is transformation from raw to central as given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralMoment.html).

I have found formulas for obtain raw co-moment matrices (second, third and fourth co-moments) such as [image]

where $r_{t+1}$ stands for returns in time period $t+1$; $m_2$, $m_3$ and $m_4$ are the raw co-moment matrices; $s^3$ and $k^4$ are the third and fourth central co-moment matrices, $\mu_i$ stands for mean of $r_i$; $\rho_{ij}$ for correlation and $\sigma_i$ for volatility of asset $i$. The volatilities come from GARCH model.

The co-skewness and co-kurtosis matrices are built from residuals of the GARCH model as given in this short fragment which also explains the notation of $i, j, k, l$. It is important to note that in the first fragment (in my opinion) there should be $s_{ijkt+1}$ and $k_{ijklt+1}$ without the third and fourth power.

[image]

From what I gather these are the formulas for transforming raw moments into central ones (binomial transform), where some elements are moved from the LHS to the RHS and vice versa. Thus, binomial transform is used to obtain the raw moments instead of the inverse binomial transform.

Is such approach to obtaining raw co-moment matrices correct?

Comment: I am confused by your question, am not sure what you are asking, or even what you are describing. You 'define' $m$ and $s$ and $k$, but leave unstated $r$, $\mu$, $\rho$ and $\sigma$. You should also define your use of 'co-moment', and your $i, j, k, l, t+1$ notation.

Comment: @wolfies I added more detailed description, as per your suggestion. Let me know if more details are necessary to fully understand the problem.